# Async execution of a long-running stored procedure via a webservice

Tags: c#, asynchronous, async-await

I have a SQL Server stored procedure responsible for manipulating a large amount of data that takes anywhere from 15 seconds to several minutes to run. I am trying to execute it asynchronously using an async MVC action invoked by a request from a desktop UI client. I seem to be doing everything exactly the way .NET async books and tutorials teach, yet it seems the stored procedure gets aborted shortly after start.

Upon start, the stored procedure adds a record to the status table to indicate a job in progress. Upon a successful completion, the stored procedure updates the status record with a success flag, and any errors are handled by a TRY-CATCH block that updates the status record with an error flag.

This has been thoroughly tested in SQL Server Management Studio, so I am certain the stored procedure can't just bomb quietly. However, when the stored procedure is executed via the async call (see below), the job record is inserted into the status table, but it doesn't get updated, which means the stored procedure never reaches its end and is terminated mid-flight, possibly due to a closed database connection.

The stored procedure call is wrapped in this async repository method:

```
    public async Task ProcessCatalogUpdateAsync(Guid updateID)
    {
        try
        {
            using (var cmd = new SqlCommand("ProcessCatalogUpdate", new SqlConnection(_connectionString)))
            {
                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                cmd.CommandTimeout = 0;
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@UpdateID", SqlDbType.UniqueIdentifier).Value = updateID;

                cmd.Connection.Open();        

                await cmd.ExecuteNonQueryAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            var message = String.Format("Error processing catalog update ID={0}", updateID);
            throw new DataException(message, ex);
        }
    }
```

The controller action looks like this:

```
    public async Task UpdateCatalog(string updateID)
    {
        var uid = Guid.Empty; // breakpoint here
        if (!Guid.TryParse(updateID, out uid))
            throw new Exception("Bad UpdateID in request!");

        await _repository.ProcessCatalogUpdateAsync(uid);

        System.Diagnostics.Trace.WriteLine("Catalog update completed"); // breakpoint here
    }
```

I've built a test harness in the form of a simply HTML page that asynchronously invokes the action using jQuery like so:

```
    var requestURL = "/catalog/updateCatalog?updateID=" + $("#updateID").val();

    $.ajax({
        url: requestURL,
        type: "GET",
        error: function (xhr, status, errorText) {
            alert("Error: " + errorText); // breakpoint here
        },
        success: function () {
            alert("Call returned!"); // breakpoint here
        }
    });
```

I put breakpoints at both alerts in the JavaScript as well as at the beginning of my controller action method to confirm that the action is actually executed. I also have a breakpoint at the `System.Diagnostics` line immediately after the `await` call to the repository method to catch when the method returns (although it may be pointless in a debugging session as the thread context is likely to be different).

This is what happens:

- The breakpoint at the beginning of the `UpdateCatalog` action is hit
- The stored procedure inserts a new row into the status table
- The `success` JavaScript handler never fires
- The status table is never updated with either a success or error flag
- The breakpoint at `System.Diagnostics` is never hit

What am I doing wrong?

---

**UPDATE**

As it turned out, there was a problem in the stored procedure code itself that at the very end was doing something that was taking over 20 minutes to complete. I have now rewritten it to work several orders of magnitude faster. However, the async stuff still isn't working the way I expect it. The jQuery AJAX `success` event fires only after the controller action method resumes after the `await` line instead of right away.

How should I change my controller action method to execute in a true "fire-and-forget" way?

Comment: "that takes anywhere from 15 seconds to several minutes to run" - the default time out of a SqlConnection is 15 seconds. Have you 1) validated the connection has been updated with a timeout of greater than the expected runtime? 2) Have you profiled the SQL Server to verify if the query is executing as expected?

Comment: `ConnectionTimeout` has nothing to do with how long the command runs, that's the `CommandTimeout`.

Comment: @MetroSmurf, I set CommandTimeout to zero (unlimited). And as I mentioned in my post, the stored proc starts executing (I know it from the presence of a new row in the status table) but never finishes.

Comment: Just because the sproc starts, does not mean it is finishing; it could be a time-out. @Crowcoder is correct with the command timeout. Have you verified that the procedure is not timing out? Have you run SQL Profiler while it is executing to see what's going on?

Comment: The stored proc wasn't timing out but there really was a problem with it, which I have now fixed. But the async execution still isn't working (please see the update in my question).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

await does not initiate work. It waits for work that is already running. Therefore, await is not a means to initiate fire-and-forget.

Change

```
await _repository.ProcessCatalogUpdateAsync(uid);
```

to

```
_repository.ProcessCatalogUpdateAsync(uid);
```

And move the diagnostic log inside ProcessCatalogUpdateAsync (or into a wrapper method). This is now fire and forget.

"fire and forget" has its perils. The work might be lost without notice, or if initiated too quickly concurrent fire and forget work might build up and overload the service.

Comment: You are correct that removing `await` and changing the controller action method to be sync rather than async did the trick. And you are correct that in most cases "fire and forget" would not be the right approach, except this is a very specific scenario where we have to do things this way and then determine the outcome of the operation by polling the status table.

Comment: That's alright. It's a form of message queuing and the queue is persistent.